# Flutter - Container width and height fit parent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `Card` widget which includes `Column` with several other Widgets. One of them is `Container`.

```
Widget _renderWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Visibility(
          visible: _isVisible,
          child: Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 200,
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: titles.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(icons[index]),
                      title: Text(titles[index]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Here, if I don't specify `width` and `height` I get error. But, is there a way to make them to fit parent element?

**EDIT**

Full code:

```
return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Card(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: new Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FormBuilder(
                        key: _fbKey,
                        autovalidate: true,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FormBuilderDropdown(

                             onChanged: (t) {
                                setState(() {
                                  text = t.vrsta;
                                });
                              },
                              validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
                              items: user.map((v) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: v,
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Image.asset(
                                        'assets/img/car.png',
                                        width: 50,
                                        height: 50,
                                      ),
                                      title: Text("${v.vrsta}"),
                                    ));
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(child: _renderWidget()),
                      text.isEmpty
                          ? Container()
                          : RaisedButton(
                              child: Text("Submit"),
                              onPressed: () {
                                _fbKey.currentState.save();
                                if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  print(_fbKey.currentState.value.toString());
                                  print(formData.startLocation);
                                  getAutocomplete();
                                }
                              },
                            )
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `ListView` inside `Column` which is why you need to specify height in your `Container` to prevent errors.

The best way is to use `Expanded` or `Flexible` as parent of your `ListView`

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(...)
)
```

Update:

```
Widget _renderWidget() {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Visibility(
        visible: _isVisible,
        child: Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: titles.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(icons[index]),
                  title: Text(titles[index]),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: But then I get error: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: It's working for me, I tested your code, make sure you remove `Container` widget

Comment: Still it is not working. I have Container - Column - Container - Expanded - ListView.

Comment: Again not sure why it didn't work, can you please post full code?

Comment: Thanks for updating it, but the current post is having many variables that I am not having access to. Can you again update it in such a manner that it becomes easy to reproduce?

Answer (score 5):

Just set the `height` and `width` property of your Container to `double.infinity`

Solution Code:

```
Widget _renderWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Visibility(
          visible: _isVisible,
          child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: titles.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(icons[index]),
                      title: Text(titles[index]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```